# How to read the header when opening a page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, web, blazor-webassembly

The webview2 has the following code that sets the token in the header when the page is opened.

```
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
var request = webView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(url, "GET", Stream.Null, "");
request.Headers.SetHeader("bearer", token);
webView21.CoreWebView2.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(request);
webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url);
```

You need to read this token when opening the page. How to do it?

(front : Blazor WASM , back : asp.net core)

Comment: Could you please [have a look this implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42179#issuecomment-692629062) regarding your concern

Comment: Did you tried the above provided steps? Was the problem resolved?